# Python GraphQL variable not defined

Tags: python, graphql, apollo-client, graphene-python

I'm trying to do a GraphQL request that contains some variables using the `apollo-boost` client on a Flask + Flask-GraphQL + Graphene server.

```
let data = await client.query({
  query: gql`{
    addItemToReceipt(receiptId: $receiptId, categoryId: $categoryId, value: $value, count: $count) {
      item {
        id
        category { id }
        value
        count
      }
    }
  }`,
  variables: {
    receiptId: this.id,
    categoryId: categoryId,
    value: value,
    count: mult
  }
})
```

But I get "Variable X is not defined" errors.

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$receiptId" is not defined., Location: [object Object],[object Object], Path: undefined
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$categoryId" is not defined., Location: [object Object],[object Object], Path: undefined
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$value" is not defined., Location: [object Object],[object Object], Path: undefined
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$count" is not defined., Location: [object Object],[object Object], Path: undefined
[Network error]: Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
```

I've added some debug prints to the `graphql_server/__init__.py`

```
# graphql_server/__init__.py:62
all_params = [get_graphql_params(entry, extra_data) for entry in data]
print(len(all_params))
print(all_params[0])
# ...
```

But from the output I get, everything seems to be OK. The `graphql_server.run_http_query()` does receive all the variables.

```
GraphQLParams(query='{\n  addItemToReceipt(receiptId: $receiptId, categoryId: $categoryId, value: $value, count: $count) {\n    item {\n      id\n      category {\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      value\n      count\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n', variables={'receiptId': '13', 'categoryId': 'gt', 'value': 0, 'count': 0}, operation_name=None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug in the library itself, if you could report it as an issue with an easy way to reproduce it, it would be great!

Comment: I've posted an issue here: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-server-core/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you had not **declared** a variable before use. Your code should look like this:

```
let data = await client.query({
  query: gql`query addItemToReceiptQuery (
    $receiptId: Int, 
    $categoryId: Int, 
    $value: String, 
    $count: Int) 
{
    addItemToReceipt(receiptId: $receiptId, categoryId: $categoryId, value: $value, count: $count) {
      item {
        id
        category { id }
        value
        count
      }
    }
  }`,
  variables: {
    receiptId: this.id,
    categoryId: categoryId,
    value: value,
    count: mult
  }
})
```

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72999653/how-to-declare-variables-in-a-graphqql-query-using-the-gql-client)